# What mapping should I add to my .vimrc that will allow me to split a buffer/window vertically/horizontally in VIM?

Tags: mapping, vim

I just want to be able to split my VIM buffers/windows vertically and/or horizontally with a keyboard shortcut. I would like to use the following shortcuts:

Vertical split

```
,v
```

Horizontal split

```
,h
```

That would be a **,** *(comma)* followed by a **v** to vertically split a buffer & **,** (comma) followed by a **h** to horizontally split a buffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to learn directly the commands

```
<C-w>s
<C-w>v
```

for the horizontal and vertical splits.
I use the mapping

```
nnoremap ,w <C-w>
```

for `<C-w>` 
so for the splits I type `,ws` or `,wv`

The advantage of this is that it allows you to use `,w` for all the other mappings 
provided by `<C-w>`

One last mapping I find useful in this context is

```
nnoremap ,, <C-w><C-w>
```

for changing between the various splits.

Comment: window bellow --> ctrl-w-j  window up  ctrl-w-k  to close other windos ctrl-w-o  to close inner window ctrl-w-q

Comment: Oh never mind. I realized that C = CTRL key, w = w key and the < - > is the structure to display keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 6):

```
nnoremap ,v <C-w>v
nnoremap ,h <C-w>s
```

Comment: yes spot on. This is what I was looking for. Plus I added nnoremap ,, <C-w>w for quick switching.

Answer (score 2):

```
nnoremap ,v :vsplit<CR>
nnoremap ,h :split<CR>
```

Comment: thanks. it is interesting to see the different ways to accomplish this.